# Ajax Post to Overloading c# web service method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I have a webService in C# and it works perfectly when I don't overload it.
When i overload and post with ajax, it gives an error.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:6783/asd.asmx/add",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("this error");
    }
});
```

in C#

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "add2")]
public int add(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}

[WebMethod(MessageName = "add3")]
public int add(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a + b + c;
}
```

I added this:

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.None)]
```

And when I test web service, it works. However, it doesn't work when I called with ajax.

Comment: What kind of error are you having? CORS?

Comment: Unknown web method add.
Parameter name: methodName

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method add.
Parameter name: methodName

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: You're calling `addnumber` - that method doesn't exist. At least not in the sample code you provided

Comment: I changed it add.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a MessageName property, you must use the MessageName as your endpoint.
eg `myservice.asmx/mymessagename`

This page http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/00a8b7/web-service/ says:

> the “SumOfNums MessageName="SumOfFloats"” method will be known as
>   “SumOfFloats” for client applications.

Comment: To clarify, what you're saying is that to call the overloaded method, instead of calling "http://localhost:6783/asd.asmx/add", they need to call "http://localhost:6783/asd.asmx/add2" or "http://localhost:6783/asd.asmx/add3", correct?  If so, you should add that specific info into your answer